# How to replace a new api access token with the old one laravel passport

Tags: laravel, api, token, laravel-passport

I need to generate an access token while a method on a controller will be get called by a specific route. My question is how to generate a new access token for logged in user and replace it with the old one (in oauth_access_tokens table e.a. updating user status or token). 
 I need to delete the old access token and replace it by a new one . In my case, The passport has a life-time and every time that user does something or accomplish or fulfill an action (e.g. call a route, etc...), I need to generate a new access token and replace it to the existing one.

Comment: I think you want https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/passport#refreshing-tokens

Comment: @PrafullaKumarSahu thanks, I tried that but the given refresh token, does not authenticate the user and also, the old access token's record still exists.

Comment: You need to replace the existing one with new one.

Comment: Thanks, but can I replace the new one?

Comment: Yes, next time you can generate another refresh token using this and replace again.

Comment: @PrafullaKumarSahu Thanks, Would you please explain to me more about how to generate a new token and replace with the old one?

Comment: Okay, once I leave the office, I will post an answer, if it will remain unsolved.

Comment: thank you so much, the question is not solved yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In [documentation](http://laravel.com/docs/6.x/passport#refreshing-tokens), it is pretty clearly mentioned, you need to use your access token, to generate a refresh token and you can replace your existing access token with that.

```
$http = new GuzzleHttp\Client;

$response = $http->post('http://your-app.com/oauth/token', [
    'form_params' => [
        'grant_type' => 'refresh_token',
        'refresh_token' => 'the-refresh-token',
        'client_id' => 'client-id',
        'client_secret' => 'client-secret',
        'scope' => '',
    ],
]);

return json_decode((string) $response->getBody(), true);
```

now there are a number of options you could employ:

- Revoke when the refresh token has been used and a new access token
  has been issued
- Revoke manually by the user associated with the token
- Revoke after a pre-determined amount of time

Look at `oauth_access_tokens` and `oauth_refresh_tokens`, tables, that will help you to understand what you need to update here manually.